# What's the name of this quantile curve estimation technique?

Tags: estimation, predictive-models, inference, quantiles

I'm still working with the same dataset as in [a previous question here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/68279/3794).

Quantile regression has taken me some way, and now I'm going further. The underlying relationship between these x and y variables has no reason to be linear. Monotonic increasing (plus noise), but not linear, and not necessarily *strictly* increasing - it can plateau in sections.

So, I've applied a new algorithm, to try to pick out the underlying curve. The thing is, I've just developed this by playing with the data. I'm pretty sure I've reinvented someone's wheel, as it's not a particularly deep algorithm, and there's little new under the sun. (and I'm not yet sure if the wheel is square or round).

Here's the curve I've derived from some of the data from [the previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/68279/3794).

[image]

Here's how I did it.

I've got a set of several thousand paired observations $(x,y)$.

First I create a set of points $X$ by dividing the x-axis up across N evenly-spaced points, with $x_{k+1}=x_k+I$, i.e. interval width $I$ between them. For each value $x \in X$, I take the subset of observations which have an x value in the range $[x-mI,x+mI]$, for some value of smoothing parameter $m$: in the case illustrated, $m=5$. Then, I take a particular quantile $q$ of the y-values of those observations - e.g. the median ($q=0.5$) - and that's the y-value of the estimated curve at point $x$.

For any $m>0.5$, the subsets of observations for two neighbouring points $x_k, x_{k+1}$, overlap.

So, there are three parameters to choose in any curve construction: $I,m,q$.

N is calculated just by dividing the range of observed $x$ by $I$ and rounding up.

**What is the name of the technique that I've reinvented? And is it a known Good Thing, or a Bad Thing?** It seems useful, and I'd like to write up my work to date; so I'd like to get the name of the algorithm right, and check the literature to see if this approach is sane and (ideally) robust.

This isn't spline-smoothing (no knots), and it doesn't seem to fit into the class of general additive models either. It does seem to handle the vicious heterskedasticity in my data pretty well. It's not quantile regression, because it's definitely not fitting a straight line (and does seem somewhat superior to the quantile regression I did previously). I don't yet have a rigorous basis for optimising the smoothing parameters; I do have some faith that a meaningful metric could be defined.

Comment: 2 parts - 1  the smoothing parameter and finding the quantile part is near synonymous with [quantile regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression). The second is allowing the function to be non-linear in particular ways. Popular techniques are smoothing splines (see [GAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_additive_model) for some related background) and both are implemented in the [quantreg R package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantreg/quantreg.pdf) (see the `rqss` function). Also related see the [VGAM package](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~yee/VGAM/).

Comment: Ok, if you want a note on something *similar* to what you are doing, it is essentially a running quantile, not much different than say the procedures [Tukey suggests](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/smooth.html), albeit likely more influenced by the choice of the bins. Why you would want to do this over quantile regression while allowing for non-linearities via splines is a bit strange to me (I know what you are doing isn't splines - it was just my suggestion as to other tools you should examine).

Comment: Also note that quantile regression when using splines isn't fitting a straight line either! Again, it was a suggestion to *accomplish the same goal* while not reinventing the wheel. Both of the suggestions for quantile regression and GAM's avoid needing to define bins or your window parameter.